# SpringBoot UnfinishedStubbingException with RestTemplate mock

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito, resttemplate

I am trying to mock RestTemplate but I when debugging I see the error bellow, which produces a null pointer:

> Method threw 'org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnfinishedStubbingException' exception. Cannot evaluate org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity$$EnhancerByMockitoWithCGLIB$$3c63496d.toString()

[image]

This is the line of code that I am trying to test :

```
 ResponseEntity<EmailEntity[]> response =
            restTemplate.exchange(apiURI, HttpMethod.GET, entity, EmailEntity[].class);

    EmailEntity[] partialEmailEntity = response.getBody();
```

**response.getBody()** returns a null.

This is a piece of code in my test :

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class EmailItemReaderTest {

@Mock
private RestTemplate restTemplate;

@InjectMocks
private EmailItemReader reader;


@Before
public void setUp(){
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}
...
...
ResponseEntity<EmailEntity> mockEntity = Mockito.spy(new ResponseEntity(mockObject, HttpStatus.OK));

    doReturn(mockEntity).when(restTemplate).exchange(
            Mockito.any(URI.class),
            Mockito.any(HttpMethod.class),
            Mockito.any(HttpEntity.class),
            EmailEntity[].class);

    reader.read();
```

Comment: Assuming that you are using the injected EmailItemReader bean, looks like you aren't injecting your mocks into the spring application context. Take a look at this [MockBean](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/mock/mockito/MockBean.html) annotation.

Comment: Tried to follow the resource you suggested, now I am getting **InvalidUseOfMatcherException**

Comment: You can't mix `matchers` and non matchers in the same argument list. For the last parameter try `eq(EmailEntity[].class)`